# How to avoid tab spaces and line number differences in SVN diff command ? Below is the command used?

Tags: svn, diff

SVN Diff Command:  svn diff -x -b -x -w --notice-ancestry --non-interactive -x --ignore-eol-style --old=svn_url_1  --new=svn_url_2

Comment: This question is very unclear. Please provide more detail on exactly what you are trying to do, what the problem is and what you have already tried.

Comment: SVN Version used is 1.7.2

Comment: I am trying to find diff between two branches which I merged from working-branch to release. So I wanted to avoid white spaces, Tab spaces, line endings, line number changes etc. So I used the below command to get the SVN diff.  (i.e.) svn diff -x -b -x -w -x -E -x -Z -x -B --notice-ancestry --non-interactive -x --ignore-eol-style SVNURL_1 SVNURL_2 > DIFF.txt

Comment: Still I get the same Output.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the built-in diff tool can ignore whitespace.

However SVN is capable to call [external diff tool](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.externaldifftools.html), and I know some diff tools do provide options to ignore white space changes.

Comment: Could you please share the info regarding those tools ?

Comment: I am using kdiff3. There are other choices too

Answer (score 0):

use external diff - first do

> svn diff --diff-cmd echo

this will show something like this for every file chnaged.

## Index: js/cellbase/clusters.js

-u -L js/cellbase/clusters.js   (revision 114) -L js/cellbase/clusters.js       (working copy) /home/ubuntu/www/cellsight/.svn/pristine/01/015a0f09c5e4efab99633a97b41586e054f8d18f.svn-base /home/ubuntu/www/cellsight/js/cellbase/clusters.js

then use the normal external diff by diff'ing changed file with it's svn working copy

> diff -w -B js/cellbase/clusters.js /home/ubuntu/www/cellsight/.svn/pristine/01/015a0f09c5e4efab99633a97b41586e054f8d18f.svn-base

to use the w and B options or whatever option you want